# choosing specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to execute only the performance between `4:45` and `5:45`. My query:

```
 select * 
 from Interval 
 where IntervalStartDateTime Between '%04:45:00.000%' AND '%05:45:00.000%'
```

How can I perform it?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server) ?

Comment: sql  Server Management Studio

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Select * 
 From Interval 
 where cast(IntervalStartDateTime as time) Between '04:45:00' AND '05:45:00'
```

Assuming this is 4:45 AM - 5:45 AM.  Otherwise use 16:45 and 17:45